# Center a div horizontally and vertically and keep centered when resizing the parent

Tags: html, css

I want to center a div horizontally and vertically at all times.

I can reduce/increase the width of the window and the div will respond by always remaining in the center of the window

```
.cent
{
  height:50px;
  width:50px;
  background-color:black;
  margin:auto;
}
```

Here is a [JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/tVuS6/) of what I have currently.
But I want to keep the div centered vertically as well so if I reduce/increase the height of the window the the div will respond by staying in the middle of the window.

In regards to the example, I want to keep the blackbox vertically centered on window resize in the same way it always stays in the center horizontally.

Comment: look at this :)

http://tutorialzine.com/2010/03/centering-div-vertically-and-horizontally/

Comment: @Aaron Which of the solutions are you referring to?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can do this with **CSS tables**:

**[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/tVuS6/14/)**

### Markup

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="cent"></div>
</div>
```

(Relevant) CSS

```css
    html,body
    {
        height: 100%;
    }
    body
    {
       display: table; 
       margin: 0 auto;
    }
    
    .container
    {  
        height: 100%;
        display: table-cell;   
        vertical-align: middle;    
    }
    .cent
    {
        height: 50px;
        width: 50px;
        background-color: black;      
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```css
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -25px;
    margin-top: -25px;
```

Answer (score 1):

Demo link is **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/tVuS6/6/)**

```css
    .cent
    {
        height:50px;
        width:50px;
        background-color:black;
        margin:auto;
        position:absolute;
        left:50%;
        top:50%;
        margin-left:-25px;
        margin-top:-25px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Test this

```
.cent {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: black;

    position:absolute;
    left:0; 
    right:0;
    top:0; 
    bottom:0;
    margin:auto;

    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

here you have a example: http://jsbin.com/iquviq/30/edit

Comment: This will make the div flow off of the top of the page when the window is vertically smaller than the height.

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
 .cent
   {
      height:50px;
      width:50px;
      background-color:black;
      margin:auto;
      margin-top:50%;
   }
```

Comment: The div is now 25px lower than the window center. And when the window resizes, it won't give the effect Aaron wants. You can easily see it when you set the height to 500px.

Answer (score 0):

try this

http://jsfiddle.net/tVuS6/4/

```
      .cent
    {
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
    background-color:black;
    margin-left: -150px;
    margin-top: -150px;
   margin:auto;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.cent
{
  height:50px;
  width:50px;
  background-color:black;
  position:absolute;
  left:50%;
  top:50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually `margin: 0 auto;` does the horizontal alignment and `vertical-align: middle` for vertical alignment.  I tried it but not working.

Try the below `css`

```
.cent {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background: #222;
    position: absolute;
    margin: -50px 0 0 -50px;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
}
```

Check it in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tVuS6/7/).

To know more about the trick check [Dead Center an Element](http://designshack.net/articles/css/how-to-center-anything-with-css/).