# How to vertically center align a div while using bootstrap layout

Tags: html, css

I have the following code snippet:

```css
#content{
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div id="content">
                    <h1>Sample Text</h1>
                    <h3>Subtext to the intro to the site</h3>
                    <hr>
                    <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Get Started!</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I'm using Bootstrap's grid system.  I want to be able to vertically center the contents of the div with `id="content"` (basically I want the whole content to be horizontally and vertically centered even as the page is resized).  This is meant to be a splash page with an image as the background.  How can I do that using CSS?  `vertical-align: middle` does not work.

And just for my learning, does `text-align: center` basically center any element even though the name seems to indicate it is for text?

Comment: are you using bootstrap 4? check the [flex implementation of bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/#align-items)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17521229/4229270

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13075912/4229270

Comment: I am using bootstrap 3.3.5.  I will play with the pointers provided and maybe come up with a solution.  However, the answers provided do not factor that I explicitly said I want a solution that does not alter the current setup I have using the bootstrap grid system.

Answer (score 0):

```
.container .row div
{
   display: table; 
   margin: 0 auto;
}

#content
{  
    height: 100%;
    display: table-cell;   
    vertical-align: middle;    
}
```

Comment: Although this may answer the questions, you may wan't to provide some extra details and explain the answer. In it's current state this answer is low-quality.